# Starting QThread/QTimer makes the qt/qml application crash with std::bad_alloc on a Raspberry Pi device

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, embedded, raspberry-pi3, qthread

I have developed a dashboard(Qt/qml) software. I have implemented a worker class to generate the data for the dashboard.

I moved the worker class to a QThread to make the application multi-threaded. And used a QTimer to trigger the doWord() slot:

```
TController::TController(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    _worker = new TDataLoader;
    _worker->moveToThread(&_workerThread);

    _timer.setInterval(50);
    _rpms_timer.setInterval(200);

    connect(&_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), _worker, SLOT(doWork()));
    connect(&_rpms_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), _worker, SLOT(readRPMs()));

    _workerThread.start();

    _timer.start();
    _rpms_timer.start();
}
```

In the worker methods of 'doWork' and 'readRPMS', only some lists are emitted.

This app is working without problem in win and it runs for some days without any problems. But If I run it on raspberry pi, I get following error after some seconds:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

Also I tried to comment the connections. But the error still occurred! Even I tried to remove the qthread to work only with QTimer, but surprisingly the error occurred again!

So what's the problem of using QThread or QTimer in Raspberry Pi?

Comment: "_So what's the problem of using QThread or QTimer in Raspberry Pi?_" - Occam's Razor suggests the question should be "So what's the problem with _my_ code?", which from the fragment posted is probably impossible to tell.  Most probably a memory leak.  In the windows implementation use task manager to see if your process's memory usage is continuously rising.  It will take a lot longer to fail on Windows, but may still be broken.

Comment: There is no memory leak. I'm just suspicious in using of qml. I can upload the whole project

Comment: Memory leak or a corrupted heap - either way it cannot be diagnosed from the information provided.  Use a debugger (GDB).  My point is between a large body of mature code used by thousands of developers, and your freshly minted code, I am not sure why you would _start_ by suspecting the issue is with Qt.